# how to ignore input to dialog based application while QProcess is running

Tags: pyqt5

I created a basic "Dialog without buttons" application using Qt5 Designer. I have a context menu that starts a QProcess that allows the user to view/edit a file. The main dialog seems disabled while the QProcess is running, but it is still processing input and when the user closes the editor, the main dialog processes all of its queued up input events. I would like the dialog to ignore all input while the QProcess is running. I would like the main dialog to be modal, but I can't seem to make it modal. How can I ignore all input to the main dialog while the QProcess is running?

```
class Ui_GitStatusDialog(QDialog):
# member variables
startDirs    = []
exceptDirs   = []
isVerbose    = False
terminal     = ''
standardView = ''
imageView    = ''

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
    Dialog.resize(724, 612)
    ...


def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.ContextMenu and source is self.fileList:
        path = self.repositoryList.currentItem().text()
        file = source.currentItem().text()
        ext  = file[1 + file.find('.'):]
        endOfFile = 2 + file.find(':')
        contextMenu  = QMenu()
        normAct      = None
        diffAct      = None
        imageAct     = None
        bDisplayMenu = False
        action       = None

        if ext == 'png' or ext == 'jpg' or ext == 'bmp':
            imageAct = contextMenu.addAction('image view')
            bDisplayMenu = True
        elif file.startswith('modified: '):
            diffAct = contextMenu.addAction('difference view')
            normAct = contextMenu.addAction('normal view')
            endOfFile += 1
            bDisplayMenu = True
        elif file.startswith('untracked: ') or  \
            file.startswith('added: ') or      \
            file.startswith('copied: ') or     \
            file.startswith('renamed: '):
            normAct = contextMenu.addAction('normal view')
            endOfFile += 1
            bDisplayMenu = True
        elif endOfFile == 1:
            normAct = contextMenu.addAction('normal view')
            bDisplayMenu = True
        
        if bDisplayMenu:
            action = contextMenu.exec_(event.globalPos())
            if action != None:
                if action == imageAct:
                    command = self.imageView + ' ' + path + file[endOfFile:]
                    process = QProcess(self)
                    # self.btnClose.setEnabled(False) - this doesn't work
                    # self.btnRefresh.setEnabled(False) - this doesn't work
                    # self.hide() - this doesn't work
                    self.setModal(True) - this doesn't work
                    process.start(command)
                    process.waitForFinished()
                    # self.btnClose.setEnabled(True)
                    # self.btnRefresh.setEnabled(True)
                    return True
                elif action == normAct:
                    ...
```

Comment: [`waitForFinished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) clearly says that it "**Blocks** until the process has finished". Just disable the dialog and connect the `finished` signal to a function that enables it again, and obviously remove `waitForFinished()`. You can't make a dialog modal to an external program, by the way. The best you could try is to set the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` window flag.

Comment: I ended up hiding my dialog while QProcess was running and showing it when QProcess finished. Is there a way to make my dialog modal? Does it need a parent window to make it a modal dialog? How would I do this?

Comment: A modal window should always have a parent, you can make it global for the application (so that it would be the only window that would accept user input until it's closed), but that's only valid for the current application. As said above, you cannot make a window modal to another, external program. The only solution, assuming the other program **always** has only **one** window, would be to embed that program's window through [`createWindowContainer()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer), but that has *a lot of limitations* and it generally has more problems than benefits.